# Проблема с динамическим задание в JLabel текста

Tags: java, swing

Изучаю java и придумал для себя небольшой проэктик , вопрос в следующем.
Есть три отдельных класса{1,2,3} , первый{1} в котором есть вышеуказанный JLabel и должна отображаться некая сумма, второй{2} в котором создаются 5 JRadioButton c названием товаров , третий{3} в котором есть эти самые суммы. Во втором{2} классе я привязал к каждой JRadioButton слушателя которые отслеживают нажатия по ним и в теории должны сравнивать свое название и подбирать в соответствии с ним из третьего{3} класса соответствующею цену и устанавливать эту сумму на Jlabel из первого класса{1}.
Единственное решение которое мне приходит на ум это сделать все в одном классе с двумя внутренними но чувствую)) что есть другое решение.
P.S. В перспективе последние два класса будут брать всю информацию с базы данных но для удобства сделал все данные статичными.

Comment: правильным решением будет отделить модель от отображения. например, воспользоваться паттерном MVC.

Comment: Я бы рекомендовал на начальном этапе изучать чужие проекты, а не свои придумывать.

Comment: @НиколайБеляков Чужой проект прочитал и забыл, а свой кровью и потом но зато на долго запомнишь. Поэтому я выбрал второй вариант )

Comment: @MikhailVaysman спасибо за совет , буду разбираться .

Comment: Чужие проекты я, к примеру, храню у себя в dropbox чтобы не забыть. Не стоит изобретать велосипед когда большинство задач в программировании уже имеют решение в виде профессионального тестированного кода.

Comment: вот пример очень простого MVC https://github.com/Vaysman/SimpleMVC